# Firewall filter for subnet to allow access from Kubernetes pod?

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an instance that is on an internal subnet `10.128.0.0/20` with IP `10.128.0.53`.

I have a kubernetes service defined as:

```
mysql           ExternalName   <none>         10.128.0.53   3306/TCP       151d
```

However strangely, if I set a firewall rule to only allow `10.128.0.0/20` or `10.128.0.0/9` to the instance (at 10.128.0.53), it won't connect. It's as if the k8s service is gaining access to the subnet by some other means (NAT?)?

**What firewall rule do I apply to allow access?** I do not want to have  `0.0.0.0/0` as the source - as it is currently.

---

When the firewall rule was `0.0.0.0/0`, the tshark dump is:

````
chris@mysql8-book-1-vm:~$ sudo tshark -f "tcp port 3306" -i any
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.
Capturing on 'any'
    1 0.000000000  10.4.12.160 → 10.128.0.53  TCP 76 51818 → 3306 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=28400 Len=0 MSS=1420 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2402747230 TSecr=0 WS=128
    2 0.000055238  10.128.0.53 → 10.4.12.160  TCP 76 3306 → 51818 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28160 Len=0 MSS=1420 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=257905306 TSecr=2402747230 WS=128
    3 0.001203683  10.4.12.160 → 10.128.0.53  TCP 68 51818 → 3306 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=28416 Len=0 TSval=2402747232 TSecr=257905306
    4 0.001685970  10.128.0.53 → 10.4.12.160  MySQL 146 Server Greeting proto=10 version=8.0.16
    5 0.002183066  10.4.12.160 → 10.128.0.53  TCP 68 51818 → 3306 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=79 Win=28416 Len=0 TSval=2402747233 TSecr=257905307
    6 10.006731817  10.128.0.53 → 10.4.12.160  TCP 68 3306 → 51818 [FIN, ACK] Seq=79 Ack=1 Win=28160 Len=0 TSval=257907808 TSecr=2402747233
    7 10.050067244  10.4.12.160 → 10.128.0.53  TCP 68 51818 → 3306 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=80 Win=28416 Len=0 TSval=2402757279 TSecr=257907808
    ```
````

Comment: Try [Network Policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) to allow/restrict the access. Alternatively maybe istio?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you have a GKE service running, and you would like other instances within the `10.128.0.0/20` to access your service.

One way of achieving it via FW rules is to create an ingress rule with source range `10.128.0.0/20` and target tag the GKE nodes network tags or alternatively the destination service account used by GKE, specifying port and protocol (in your case, `TCP 3306`).